# AIX : cannot execute binary file, 0403-006 execute permission denied

Tags: mysql, permissions, binary, xampp, execute

I am working on AIX 7. I like to know more in detail about the following error scenarios

- cannot execute binary file
- 0403-006 execute permission denied

---

for the **first** case, on search it was likely that,

> when you are trying to run 64 bit software on a 32 bit OS, you may
>   have that error. AIX is 64 bit, and I have been trying to use mysql by
>   installing XAMPP, where I am getting the above error. I assume 32/64
>   bit software will be okay with 64 bit OS.

for the **second** case,

> though I have logged in as a root, and file permissions are 755 [
>   -rwxr_xr_x ] execution permission is denied..

I will be very happy, if I could know why the above situations occur and the best way to resolve it.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ls -l** to list the permissions for your files in the directory

If the file concerned does not have x (execute) you need to add it

**chmod a+x myfile.sh**

Comment: Yes, I have already made it **executable** ..

For your information,

I followed another thread, which asked to know the file type using `find <filename>`

There was difference btwn the formats for my concerned files and usual executable bin files.

So, these files may be executable, but not perfectly suiting AIX.

Thats, how I concluded !!