# Meaning of the java command in unix

Tags: java, linux, unix

I am trying to execute a .sh file kept in a Linux system. All the commands in the .sh file is working fine except one java command which is giving execute permission denied statement. Can anyone please help me in understanding the whole command and what could be the reason for the permission denied retun? I have also tried chmod 777  to obtain the permission but still the same. what is the exact meaning of -classpath .:lib/:cl-ebook-import.jar ?

The java command is-

```
   java -DCL_LOG_DIR="/Users/MO/Importebook" -classpath .:lib/:cl-ebook-import.jar org.xy.ebook.ebook.CLImportebook
```

return that I am getting is-

```
  ksh: java: 0403-006 Execute permission denied.
```

Comment: Where is your `java`? You can find it out by `which java`. Does this file has execute permission?

Comment: A duplicate, although it won't allow me to set it since it has no good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398676/aix-cannot-execute-binary-file-0403-006-execute-permission-denied

Comment: The first thing to test is to just run "java". NOthing else. And then see what happens.

Comment: When I used "which java" command I got this return-  0652-141 There is no java in /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin.....This file is executable as I was able to execute it from a .bat file kept in another system.

Comment: @Anilkumar: Ah! then the answer is easy! You need to install Java. A JRE actually. The Java Runtime Environment. You don't need the development tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact meaning of the command is to launch Java. It tells Java the Class Path, which is where Java will look for classes to load. The paths are separated by colons. So what that -classpath argument is telling Java is to look for classes in . (the current directory), lib/ and cl-ebook-import.jar.

Then it tells Java to launch org.xy.ebook.ebook.CLImportebook as the main class of an application.

The -DCL_LOG_DIR tells Java to set a property named CL_LOG_DIR to "/Users/MO/Importebook".

And you know, are you sure this is a Linux system? Because that path looks like Mac OS X to me.

Comment: Does lib/ directory has special meaning in Linux system? Where can I find this? any command to look for this directory?

Comment: @Anilkumar: No special meaning. That is not an absolute path because it does not start with / so it means a directory under the current directory named lib. The shell script probably locates its install location and does a "cd" command before trying to launch this program.

Comment: I don't see any lib folder in the current directory. is it fine?

Comment: you are right, -DCL_LOG_DIR is in .sh script for MAC OS... I actually have to write a new .sh file for Linux system which must work like the .sh file available for MAC OS. Can you please let me know what will be corresponding command for -DCL_LOG_DIR in Linux sytem?

Comment: @Anilkumar: Set it to whatever directory you want log files written to. I would assume, because of the name.